# Is it possible to implement a bidirectional relationship between two structs using only constant properties?

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming, immutability, lenses

My use case is based on the following model:

```
struct Person {
  let name: String
  let houses: [House]
}

struct House {
  let owner: Person
}
```

Now, ideally I would like to maintain a bidirectional relationship that requires every house to have exactly one owner where an owner should also know all its houses.

Using the above data structures, is it possible to create instances of `House` and `Person` such that there is a relationship between the two and the objects are essentially pointing at each other?

I guess the phrasing of this already is somewhat misleading, because due to the value semantics of `struct`s, they don't really point anywhere but are only holding copies of values. It seems to be like it should be obvious that it's not possible to create these two objects with a bidirectional relationship, but I still wanted to be sure and ask this questions here!

An obvious solution would also be to make `houses` and `owner` variables using `var` instead of `let` when declaring them, then the relationship could be maintained in the initializer of each `struct`:

```
struct Person {
  let name: String
  var houses: [House]

  init(name: String, houses: [House]) {
    self.name = name
    self.houses = houses
    self.houses = houses.map { (house: House) in
      var newHouse = house
      newHouse.owner = self
      return newHouse
    }
  }
}


struct House {
  var owner: Person

  init(owner: Person) {
    self.owner = owner
    var newHouses = self.owner.houses
    newHouses.append(self)
    self.owner = Person(name: owner.name, houses: newHouses)
  }
}
```

However, what if I want to keep `houses` and `owner` constant? As I said, it seems to be obvious that it's not possible, but I'm wondering if there's some fancy (maybe functional) way to achieve this? I was thinking about [lenses](http://chris.eidhof.nl/post/lenses-in-swift/), which can be used as *getters* and *setters* when dealing with immutable models.

Comment: I would strongly discourage the creation of any sort of *"truly self-referential"* in-memory data structures ... in Swift or in any other programming language. Why? Because it makes things very difficult for the memory manager: it can lead to "memory leaks" due to circular references. Also: don't make these "just structs."  Let them be the "objects" that they naturally are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're describing sounds more like an ORM than a language feature, and also doesn't sound appropriate to handle with value types like structs. How do you expect the language to know that `owner` is the inverse relationship property of `houses` and needs to be maintained accordingly? This is something that needs to be enforced with code is not possible with the Swift language alone.

It sounds like you're trying to maintain some kind of model object graph, which is a problem that's been solved many times over. You should take a look at [Realm DB](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) and [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html) both of which offer managed bidirectional relationships. You'll find however that neither of these are implemented with structs. The problem with using value types is that they are copy-on-write. As soon as you mutate one struct in the object graph, you'd need to reassign all of it's related things to the new, mutated copy, which then in turn are mutated and would need to update all of *their* related structs. Reference semantics (classes) make maintaining an object graph much easier as mutations don't produce new instances.

Comment: fully agree to what you say. though I don't particularly need core data or realm as both are primarily persistence layers (which I don't really care about here), however, the point that they are both implementing the bidirectional relationship using classes rather than structs is definitely valid!

Comment: @nburk Glad to help. Core Data is also usable as an in memory graph with `NSInMemoryStoreType`. They are both still powerful as object graph managers, persistence aside.

Comment: I'm wondering in general what to do in that kind of situation... do you think it'd be the solution not to use structs for the model but classes? I'm trying to maximize usage of value types in my code, and model objects seem to be a great place to use structs?! is it really not possible to do that when a bidirectional relationship is required?

Comment: @nburk You should not consider structs to be the ideal model type, because not all models are values. Especially in your case when they refer to specific instances of each other. The fact that we're using the word refer should indicate that references, not values, are appropriate.

Comment: I think I want to stick to structs and constant properties, I like that my code gets easier to reason about when I use value types. I think my solution will be to remove the requirement for a mutual connection and will only retain a connection from `Person` to `House`, so that a person still knows all its `houses`, but a house has no `owner`

Comment: @nburk I just heard about RocketData from Linkedin which is designed for managing immutable models. I don't know about two way relationships but it's worth a look: https://github.com/linkedin/RocketData

Answer (score 3):

What you want is not possible using structs. Your current solution (with `var`) doesn't work like you think it does: all values are independent copies. Consider the following example:

```
let p = Person(name: "Nick", houses: [])
let h = House(owner: p)
h.owner.houses
p.houses
```

Because each copy is independent, this means `p` isn't the same as `h.owner`.

If you need a bidirectional relationship, you should use objects with `weak` pointers (to break the reference cycle). Alternatively, you could think to see if you need the bidirectional relationship.

Comment: I settled on removing the requirement for the mutual connection between the objects for now, since I really only want to experiment and maximize usage of value types in my code to see where I run into issues with this approach. Thanks for helping out!!